# Give an example of sequence $\{f_n\}$ satisfying $f_n(x_n)=0 $ but satisfies $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Give  an example  of sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continious  real -value function on $[0, \infty)$ converging uniformly on $[0, \infty)$ to a function $f$  such that  for each $n \ge1$ there exists $x_n \in [0, \infty)$ satisfying $f_n(x_n)=0 $ but satisfies $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$

My attempt :  I take $ f_n(x)= e^{\frac{x-n}{n}} -1$

Put $x_n=n \in [0,\infty)$ , then  $ f_n(x_n)= e^{\frac{n-n}{n}}-1 =0$
but  $ f(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) =e-1 \neq0$

Comment: Does that sequence converges uniformly? I don’t think it does. For a sequence of functions to converge uniformly to a constant, all but finitely many must the functions must be bounded.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  yes because $f_n \to 0$

Comment: No, $f_n\to e-1.$ But that doesn’t mean it converges uniformly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sequence does not converge uniformly.

Try:
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$  It converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{x+1}.$

---

$f(x)$ has to be either all positive or all negative. We are choosing all positive. Then if $f_n(x)$ is supposed to be convergent to $f(x)$ uniformly, the places where $f_n(x)$ is negative, the value of $f_n(x)$ must be small. In particular, it is probably easiest to find examples where $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty.$

---

We could take any non-zero continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty.$ Then if $x_n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty,$ we can pick $f_n(x)=f(x)-f(x_n).$

In the first case, $f(x)=\frac1{1+x}$ and $x_n=n.$

But we could also use $f(x)=e^{-x},$ $x_n=\log n$ and get $f_n(x)=e^{-x}-\frac 1n.$

---

In general, we only need $f$ non-zero and continuous and $f(x_n)\to 0.$

So we could take any positive continuous $g(x)$ and define $f(x)=\frac{\cos^2 x}{x+1}+\sin^2(x)g(x).$  Then we can choose $x_n=\pi n$ and get $$f_n(x)=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{x+1}+\sin^2(x)g(x)-\frac{1}{\pi n+1}.$$

In this last case, when $\cos^2x=0,$ $f(x)=g(x)$ so we don’t require $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$

---

If $f_n(x_n)=0,$ then $x_n\to\infty.$

Otherwise, $x_n$ has a sub-sequence convergent to some real $\alpha,$ and we can use uniform convergence to show $f(\alpha)=0.$

So we can take $y_i=x_{n_i}$ a convergent subsequence to $\alpha$ and $g_i=f_{n_i}.$ Then we’ve reduced to the case of $g_i$ uniformly convergent to $f$, with $g_i(y_i)=0$ and $y_i\to\alpha.$

Then $$f(\alpha)=\lim_{i\to\infty} f(y_i)=\lim_{i\to\infty}\left(f(y_i)-g_i(y_i)\right)=0,$$ with the last due to uniform convergence of $g_i$ to $f.$

Uniform convergence also means, at least for $n$ large, $y_n=\inf_{x\in[0,\infty)} f_n(x)>-\infty.$ This is because $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<1$ for $n$ large and, since $f(x)>0,$ this means $f_n(x)$ is bounded below for large $n.$

So we have a sequence of constants $z_n=y_n-\frac1n$ such that $y_n\to0$ and, for sufficiently large $n,$ $g_n(x)=f_n(x)-z_n$ is a strictly positive function, and $g_n$ converges uniformly to $f.$

So this shows that all examples can be gotten by a sequence of continuous $g_n$ With the following conditions:

1. For some $N$, all $g_n$ are strictly positive when $n\geq N.$
2. $g_n\to f$ uniformly for a strictly positive $f.$
3. Some sequence $x_n\in[0,\infty)$ with $g_n(x_n)\to 0.$
4. $f_n(x)=g_n(x)-g_n(x_n).$

Of course, you need to rephrase this in the case when $f$ is strictly negative.

The early examples were $g_n=f.$

In the case when $y_n =\inf_x f_n(x)>-\infty,$ we can pick $g_n(x)=f_n(x)-y_n.$ That only makes $g_n$ non-negative, but we can restrict to $g_n$ positive by definining some positive sequence $z_n\to0$ with $g_n(x)=f_n(x)-y_n+z_n.$ (We set $g_n(x)=f_n(x)$ when $f_n$ is not bounded below.)

---

Another approach is to write $h_n(x)=g_n(x)-f(x).$ Then:

1. Given a positive continuous $f,$
2. Some sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)\to 0,$
3. Some sequence of continuous $h_n$ converging uniformly to $0.$
4. For some $N,$ and for all $x\in[0,\infty),n\geq N,$ $h_n(x)>-f(x).$

Then $f_n(x)=f(x)+h_n(x)-f(x_n)-h_n(x_n)$ is such a sequence, and all such sequences can be gotten in this way.

Our early examples were all $h_n=0.$

Comment: Indeed, if the sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $f$ is continuous; if it wasn’t all positive or all negative, the intermediate value theorem would give some $x$ for which $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ doesn’t converge uniformly on $[0,+\infty[$. Indeed, if you take $x_n=n^2$, you have:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, e^{n-1}-e=|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \leq \underset{x \in [0,+\infty[}{\sup} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
and therefore: $$\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} \underset{x \in [0,+\infty[}{\sup} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \neq 0$$